# Create service in Windows Xp with a config file

Tags: c++, configuration, windows-services, service, config

This is the command which I created a service of my program. Program normally uses a config file, but when I created this service, program could not start as a service.

```
C:\>sc create MalwareService binPath= "C:\Program Files\mbam.exe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just run any random program as a service; there is a certain [protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141.aspx) the program has to follow.